# Self Studying over lectures

Tags: graduate-school, physics, education, lecture-teaching-method

this is my first post here, I'll copy and paste a recent answer I asked in the physics and resulted a little bit inappropriate. I do physics so I'm mainly looking for answers for people in the field that maybe had some similare experience, but I think any opinion could be useful, so if I'm not out of context, thank you for any answer and here's my question:

I'm just starting what's basically the master in theoretical physics (I'm sorry, I'm not sure about the correspondence between italian and USA/UK studies. To be clearer: it's basically two years courses after the bachelor degree).

I'm having a little problem with the lectures and professors and I'd like to study and prepare exams on my own, but I'm not quite sure about this choice. The problem is that theoretical physics is very mathematical, and I don't ask you not to use it, but I require that you, as a physicist, don't put aside the physics to do just math. That's the point, we're doing all the math, all the calculations but we lack of things like physical interpretation of what we do, or physical reasoning, which, added to the abstractness already present on its own in theoretical physics, makes those lectures look like mathematical lectures. It's like those lectures could be done without any problem by a mathematician(with all respect to mathematicians). I'd like them to teach me how to do physics and give me tips and insights to get it, which is in my opinion the hardest thing. I can work out the mathematical passages on my own or look for them, but for the physics, at least in my case, it's way harder to figure it out and really get the physical meaning of something.

So basically I'm looking for opinion and help, to get me towards one, or the opposite direction: I'm so insecure cause I always followed lessons and this would be the first time i quit lectures and study just on my own, but I just can't stand me "paying" for physics and them "selling" me math.

So can someone help, give opinions and advices? Thanks again.

Comment: Chances are the mathematicians would not be able to do all of the calculations in theoretical physics because they would have a stroke every time the physicists say "the group SU(2) is isomorphic to the group SO(3)" ...

On a serious note, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it better, I was trying doing it in this comment but I end up repeating what I already wrote in the post, I'm basically asking for an advice: Doing something I like, on my own, that would make my exams harder, or doing something really gives me nerves but will make my exams way easier. Following lectures makes exams passing easier but I feel like I'm wasting important time I should spend studying physics for real, not the math used in physics. And since I'm no Newton I don't know if I can afford losing all this time

Comment: From my non-physicist POV, it sounds like you're finding that your view of what physics entails is different from the institution's view. Is it possible that another institution would do things differently (i.e., more like your view)? Alternatively, is it possible that you've misunderstood what the subject involves and all institutions would teach the subject similarly? I don't have the answers, but the questions seem, at least to my lay-mind, worth considering.

Comment: If I read your question right, I think you're asking: Should you study for exams/masters/PhD? Or, should you just keep studying theoretical physics at home without even thinking of what's happening at school? Am I close? Or totally off track?

Comment: @Ian_Fin I can talk about just another institution and I can say they do things a little bit differently, let's say more physical, sadly I couldn't join them. It may be aswell that almost all institutions teach it in the way I don't like, and to be clear, I think that what they teach are things ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY for a physicist, the problem is that there are other things even more important than those things, and they are sometimes ignored. As I said i can use two hours to work out the math on my own, but physical reasoning and insights are way harder to grasp and they have to be privileged

Comment: @scaaahu You're right there, I still wouldn't like to totally isolate. I want finish the master and get the phd, in order to be still in the field and have the chance to talk about physics, share ideas and work with better physicist than me, who can add something to my life, my mind and my understanding of the subject

Comment: @Angeloferrari You say in your question that you've just started a two year degree. Are you sure that all of this physical stuff that you consider to be even more important won't come later? Mikey Mike's question suggests you need to learn the maths before you can learn the physics. Perhaps you're in this first "learning the maths" stage now?

Comment: Suggestions for possible immediate use (without addressing your underlying problems/concerns): If you're not familiar with *The Feynman Lectures on Physics*, you may want to start there and see whether this helps. Also, simply looking through the books at you university's library might lead you to some useful reading material. Finally, you can try googling various phrases you are interested in physical intuition about simultaneously with phrases such as "physical meaning", "big picture", "what it means", etc.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'm familiar with Feynmann books, I loved them and studied for them(especially volume 2) during my undergraduate courses. Anyway you're suggesting me to look for textbooks where I can study the stuff on my own if I'm correct.

Comment: @Ian_Fin Yeah it's a 2 years degree, I think it's called master in USA, it follows the bachelor degree which I already have in physics, so I already studied the basics of math and physics, and I'm not "unwilling" to learn the math and the "new" math required, that is absolutely necessary, I just hate doing just that, just the math.

Comment: Much of what you appear to want probably comes from group/study sessions with fellow graduate students. However, from what you have written, I suspect that you are not involved with this and that you tend to study on your own, which is why I made the "study stuff on your own" suggestions.

Comment: Yes I rarely do group study with my friends, but I don't think they could give what I look for, a professor could do that, or a very talented student (a top physicist of the next generation), and none of them are available at the moment, or I simply didn't notice someone in my classrom. Thank you for your advice anyway.

Comment: I do not know if one can actually give a good answer here; from what I read here you are unhappy with your lectures because they seem to give the math and methods not enough perspective towards physics. If you feel that way, that is what it is.If you can not stand those lectures do not attend them and learn on your own. If you work through the lecture notes and the exercise on your own I think you still have a good chance of being successful in your exams. You could also talk about it with your profs. (if you have not tried that already). Out of curiosity what lectures are we talking about?

Comment: We're talking about a course on quantum field theory, a course in relativistic quantum mechanics and a course on statistical mechanics. I haven't tried talking to them even cause I don't want to be disrespectful or ask them to change their methods just for one student (the others are mainly worried about the toughness of the subject, not about the subject itself). Thank you for your advice

Comment: Please edit the post to include an actual question.

Comment: @JeffE  Edited, hope it's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question touches a subtle point.

Physics looks like it is a form of math, but it is very different in how it is approached. This complicates the physical interpretation.

Let me start with a tacky comparison - think of the following: physics is like programming in a dynamic language (say Python), math is like programming in a statically typed language, (say C++). In the latter, you declare all ahead of time, make the assumptions clear and build things up just as if you knew where you wanted to go all along.

In the former, on the other hand, you can build up your concepts just on the fly, as you go, and, while in programming that's probably bad practice, that's what actually happens in physics.

The property of physical concepts are, even if they are of mathematical nature, essentially "duck-typed" - you use whatever feature you want from them, and when it fails, you tack on some other concept, just as required. Just look at pseudo-vectors (e.g. angular momentum) - they are indistinguishable from vectors for almost all operations, except when you mirror them (in 3D), that's when the equivalence breaks down.

A mathematician would exclaim in horror that a pseudo-vector constitutes the wrong concept and the right thing to use instead would be a 2-form. It is clear that the mathematician would have wanted the concept to be defined/agreed upon in the beginning, while the physicist is happy to adjust his interpretation post-hoc, as phenomena (in this case, a computational/theoretical one, but it could be experimental) are discovered.

This causes the main misunderstanding between mathematicians and physicists; and I believe it is also at the core of your question - when you ask, where is the physics, I suspect you find it difficult to disentangle where one just runs down a mathematical/computational formalism, and where true (physical) assumptions are made.

For this, I recommend actually taking the mathematician's stance and to pull apart what the assumptions are in a model from the computations that follow from these assumptions. The idea is to make it precisely transparent what is a physical assumption/property of your space, and what is a mathematical consequence. It is then the job of the physicist to fill the conclusions with physical meaning/interpretation.

You are not being taught to do proper modelling and interpretation? No surprise, this is not something that happens often, usually only at paradigm shifts, so your professors will be out of practice in this respect. No, your professors most likely do not sell you math. Rather, I suspect, they sell you some conglomerate of mathematical notation and derivation, "duck-typed" with physical assumptions throughout.

There are some books which are a bit cleaner about separating the levels (e.g. Wu/Sachs for General Relativity), and I am sure there is more, but I am out of the field now and am not up-to-date about further good literature to get a clearer handle on things.

**In short:** It is not the math-heaviness that you most likely suffer from, but the lack of clarity which part of the discussion presented to you is physical assumption, which part is abstraction, and which part is technical derivation.

Comment: Although this answer makes some reasonable point, it needlessly parodies mathematicians' viewpoints on things...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help. I have to agree with you, I'll start from the end, the "in short" part: that's exactly what I meant, I don't despise math-heaviness, I actually like it when it's clear what we are doing. You expressed my problem in a better way, so thank you. About the paradigm shift part and the reason they can't teach me proper modelling and interpretation, I'm not sure I got it, so could you elaborate it more?

Comment: @paulgarrett I studied mathematics and physics and found myself, during my TA time the goto-point for students from both topics to understand the "others" viewpoint. Above, I simplified the situation description because I believe it is useful to help OP understand what the problem is - I have actually great sympathy for the mathematicians point of view. It is *not* meant as polemics, but rather to help the OP see straight what the problem is, instead of a even longer-winded, verbose explanation.

Comment: But I disagree that what is portrayed is "the mathematicians'" viewpoint, simplified or not. Perhaps that of math grad students or undergrads, and certainly a common belief among physics grad students, and so on. But this caricature disserves all parties. Lengthy observation does suggest that undergrads and grad students often do have somewhat exaggerated viewpoints, but I'd claim that working mathematicians do not necessarily share those simpler caricatured outlooks... exactly because they are inaccurate and unhelpful.

Comment: @Angeloferrari Good point, I was too brief on that: when a technique is discovered and introduced or a concept is generalised, its inventors know how/why this happened. They have a clear picture of the needs/gaps that are closed by this new concept or experiments. After a while, the technique becomes common knowledge/routine. Explanations and contexts are forgotten and often not taught anymore. Perhaps they can be taken for granted, but the student doesn't know that. Often, active scientists do not practice this type of justification, because in much of the day-to-day work, it's unnecessary.

Comment: @paulgarrett The OP obviously found the explanation helpful. I do not know how to reformulate it so that it won't offend you and would continue to make a crisp point. Yes, we are talking students here, so I am happy to change that, if that's the point of contention. Feel free to make a suggestion how to improve the formulation without losing clarity.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Thank you, I think I get what you meant now.

Comment: I think it's just that factual inaccuracy tends to be not a good thing. It is a palpable fact that factually inaccurate explanations are often more palatable than accurate ones. It's not that mathematicians universally insist on "logical order" and never work heuristically or iteratively or invoking physical intuition, I can attest. So to explain (to a beginner) that their mathematical difficulties are due to viewpoint quirks of mathematicians is an unhelpful misattribution: it is the beginner's own inexperience with the mathematics... and possibly incomprehension of this by people... [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] ... who _could_ be clarifying helpfully. There is no need to ascribe exaggerated behaviors to mathematicians/physicists to discuss the several different threads of thought in doing any kind of science... I only mention this because such stuff too easily turns into demonizing of "the other", probably not helpful in the long run, etc.

Comment: I speak from my very own experience, and I believe that I have the right to do so as long as it was my honest observation. What you call "exaggerated" behaviour was a pretty accurate description of my own experience. I am sure that mathematicians have a whole batch of intuitions working for them, but in *every single* collaboration with mathematicians I ever had (not just as student), I had a hard time talking to them, unless I managed to precisely "declare" what am I talking about in a quite precise "syntax". Which is perfectly fine. I do not see what this has to do with "demonisation".

Comment: If you have a different experience, that's fair enough. However, either by luck, coincidence or misfortune, this is mine. So, actually, what I said in my answer was not even meant as a caricature - it reflects my own experience. That being said, I only ever worked with mathematicians from continental Europe, esp. Germany, which may, of course, colour my perception.

Answer (score 3):

Although many physicists tend to like more the physics than the mathematical details, it is crucial for a physicist to master the required mathematical details. Understanding all the mathematical concepts  give you a high level of mathematical techniques which can be applied to various theories in physics. My advice would be to go to the courses, and also to study in great detail what you really like in your spare time, perhaps guided by a professor. Unfortunately, in physics, one must learn the mathematical language, and then the physics associated.

Comment: I totally agree about the importance of math which I personally love, and for a theoretical physicist is required a deep knowledge of math in my opinion. But to do physics you need way more than just that math, if it wasn't like that, mathematicians would do physics. And it's the lack of the physical aspects in my courses that bothers me, not the mathematics. It's the use of math without thinking about the physics you're doing. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: _if it wasn't like that, mathematicians would do physics_ — So?  Many mathematicians *do* do physics.  Is that supposed to be a bad thing?

Comment: It's not a bad thing, it just isn't the same thing. You can't simply do physics with just mathematics, that's what i meant. You need math to do it but if math is all you need we would just have mathematicians doing it, not physicist.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should ask this on the Physics site too.

It sounds like this department might be a mismatch for you.  You might want to look around for a different school to transfer to.  Before deciding, visit some classes that you would take next semester and next year.  Maybe the professors you have this semester are not representative of your department's approach in general.

I understand your trepidation, your reluctance, to stop attending lectures.  On the other hand, I understand the temptation.  Not attending frustrating lectures might give you more time and energy to focus on your self-study.

I would suggest that you avoid an all-or-nothing approach.  Pick one class to experiment in with your non-attendance idea.

There is the tiniest chance your current state of mind could be part of a change in your medical condition.  It couldn't hurt to go get a check-up and let the doctor know how school is going for you.

But I think the mostly likely explanation of your current frustration is that

(a) not all physics teaching is good;

(b) sometimes a class is taught well but it's not a good fit for an individual student;

(c) you may have had bad luck this semester -- the ideal scenario is to have a variety of courses at any given time, so you can do some work that emphasizes mathematical manipulations, but have balance out with experimental work that helps you grasp the physics in a meaningful way.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped and added the comment before i was finished. I didn't really get the medical condition part. You're saying that my frustration and state of mind may affect the body negatively?

Comment: @Angeloferrari - There is one possible red flag in your Question.  If you were a friend or family member I would suggest you check in with your regular doctor, for my peace of mind.  The possible red flag I saw was that what you are proposing to do is rather drastic, and your level of frustration is pretty generalized (all three of your classes).  From the limited information I have, I would guess that the chances of something going on that a medical professional might be able to help with are < 10%.  The *most* likely explanation is a mismatch with the dept, bad luck with the semester,...

Comment: ... an imbalance in the design of your program of studies, bad luck with your instructors, or some combination of those.  You know, balance is very important.  Yes, one has to do some math in order to do physics, but if you had wanted to do nothing but math, you would have joined a math department.